# What Portuguese proverb conveys "You scratch my back and I'll scratch yours"?

Tags: proverbios

I'm trying to find an equivalent proverb in Portuguese.  Literally, (tu coças as minhas costas e eu coçarei as tuas) there isn't any that I know of.  **Is there any in current usage in Brazil and/or Portugal which conveys "help me in my difficulties and I will help you in yours".**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

> **Uma mão lava a outra**

[Link in portuguese](http://cursodeingles.uol.com.br/artigos/girias-e-expressoes/como-dizer-uma-mao-lava-a-outra-em-ingles/#rmcl)

Comment: Eu também pensei nessa, mas não acho que seja exatamente a mesma coisa.

Comment: Acredito que sim, se ele referir-se a um ajudar o outro.

Comment: @JorgeB. olha o link

Comment: Eu acho que "uma mão lava a outra" é mais conotado para situações perigosas. Mas deve ser a que melhor encaixa na expressão inglesa.

Comment: Ao menos aqui no Brasil, nada tem a ver com situações perigosas, serve pra qualquer coisa em que haja troca de ajuda ou favores.

Comment: Eu conheço isto como "uma mão lava a outra, e as duas lavam a cara", no sentido de "unidos podemos mais que separados"; que lhe dá um significado mais... tangencial a (e um pouco diferente de) "eu ajudo-te e tu ajudas-me".

Comment: There's also *é dando que se recebe*.

Comment: Eu diria que o contexto em que mais vejo essa expressão ser usada é o de corrupção, especialmente [tráfico de influência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A1fico_de_influ%C3%AAncia).

Answer (score 0):

«temos de ser uns pelos outros»
Não é literal, mas tem um sentido semelhante

Comment: Olá Paulo, bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE. Você teria uma referência para esse provérbio? Não consegui achar nenhuma numa pesquisa rápida.